# Sorting a stack in descending order

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I'm having trouble sorting a stack in descending order, sorting works with the help of another stack.

here is the sorting code:

```
void* sort(stack_type* stack, stack_type* auxiliary) {
  int* element = NULL;
  while(!is_empty(stack)) {
    element = pop(stack);
    while(!is_empty(auxiliary) && head(auxiliary) > element) {
      push(pop(auxiliary), stack);
    }
    push(element, auxiliary);
  }
}
```

the output is thus:

```
|   -4  |
|   -45 |
|   356 |
|   87  |
|   76  |
|   54  |
|   34  |
|   22  |
|   8   |
|   2   |
```

but i want so:

```
|   356 |
|   87  |
|   76  |
|   54  |
|   34  |
|   22  |
|   8   |
|   2   |
|   -4  |
|   -45 |
```

here is the gist with complete code: https://gist.github.com/avoxy/380e96a87cb3c6cc1f4a62c02fb6428d

thx guys

Comment: What kinda *trouble*?

Comment: Do you implement your own stack? Instead of using a single-linked list (which is the most common way to implement a stack) use a double-linked list, and keep a pointer to both the head and the tail. Then you can iterate over the "stack" any way you want. I wouldn't call it a "proper" stack anymore though.

Comment: what kind of sorting algorithm is this supposed to be?

Comment: Why does -45 appear at the top of the stack in your desired output, instead of at the bottom?

Comment: Why does `sort()` return a value of type `void*`? ... and why is there no `return` statement inside the function?

Comment: Sufficient code needs to be presented *in the question itself* to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your algorithm will not always produce the sorted output. Check the logic

Comment: Can you better explain the output that you're looking for? I don't see the pattern. Also, have you considered using a priority queue? They can be blazing fast. You add items in any order, but they can only be removed in a particular order.

Comment: Post relevant code here at this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting by the pointers, not by the pointed-to values. In fact, you don't have pointed-to values in this case, which gives rise to the question why to use pointers at all. Anyway, this is the problematic piece of code:

```
push((int*) -45, stack);
```

Pointers will mostly be not negative. So, this cast will cause an underflow and, depending on your compiler, will result in a large positive pointer. As such, this pointer will be larger than any of the other pointers you use (except the `-4`).

Summarizing: Do not sort by pointers (unless you really know what you're doing). Do not use pointers to represent plain integers.

Comment: another problem what i see before your help is in the head function, i removed the pointer from head function and the code work, thx.

Comment: In this case (assuming 32 bit mode), casting to pointers is effectively the same as casting to unsigned integers. So negative integers are changed to 2^32 - value, -45 is changed to 4294967251, and -4 to 4294967292, making them the two largest values.

Answer (score 0):

Your `element` variable is declared as type `int *`.  Supposing that is appropriate, in your sort you are comparing *pointers*, but you seem to want to compare the values they point *to*, instead.